# Add the customer email in Woocommerce My Account Dashboard template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, account

I would like to display email address of customer in myaccount Woocommerce panel.

I try copy/paste this part code from `thankyou` file template:

```
<?php _e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
<strong><?php echo $order->get_billing_email(); ?></strong>
```

But it doesn't work.

How i can do it?

Comment: @pokeybit Sorry and kindly but this has nothing to do with branding… The OP want just to display the email of the current customer in his my account dashboard page.

Answer (score 0):

As the `thankyou.php` template code is related the `$order` object, it's normal that it doesn't work in `myaccount/dashboard.php` template.

If you look to the existing code you will see `$current_user` variable that you can use. It's an instance of the `WP_User` object.

So instead insert the code below to the `myaccount/dashboard.php` template:

```
<p><?php _e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
<strong><?php echo $current_user->user_email; ?></strong></p>
```

OR *(the billing email)*:

```
<p><?php _e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
<strong><?php echo $current_user->billing_email; ?></strong></p>
```

Tested and works